# Access first value in tuple in Django Template HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating a website in Django and need to display a value that the user had chosen from a choice field - their  `user_status` which is stored in a tuple. The first and second values are identical, but they can be 'Member' or 'Expert'.

At first I tried this in my HTML:

```
{{ user.user_status }}
```

This was the result:

```
('Member', 'Member')
```

What I wanted was this:

```
Member
```

Next, I tried

```
{{ user.user_status.Member }}
```

The result was nothing:

Finally I tried

```
{{ user.user_status.Member.0 }}
```

The result was the first character in `('Member', 'Member')`

```
(
```

How can I access either the first or second value of this tuple and display it in my HTML?

## Edit 1:

My model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    __USER_STATUS = [('Member','Member'), ('Expert','Expert')]

    user_status = models.CharField(
        max_length = 20,
        choices = __USER_STATUS,
        default = __USER_STATUS[0], # 'Member'
    )
    phone_number = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
```

## Edit 2:

Something strange is going on...

When I use:  `{{ user.user_status  }}`

It displays `('Member', 'Member')` in the internet window opened by visual studio code.

But it displays `Member` in Firefox and Chromium.

Why is this?

Why is the same code showing different results in different browsers? I know that sometimes this happens with how the webpage looks, but this is a fundamental difference in content.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Show your models plz.

Comment: It looks like you aimed to store a 2-tuple in the field, but since it is (likely) a `CharField`, you thus converted it to a string. Now the "structure" is lost :s.

Comment: Something strange is going on...

When I use:  ``` {{ user.user_status  }} ```

It displays ``` ('Member', 'Member') ``` in the internet window opened by visual studio code.

But it displays ``` Member ``` in Firefox and Chromium.

Why is this?

Why is the same code showing different results in different browsers? I know that sometimes this happens with how the webpage looks, but this is a fundamental difference in content.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that data actually, is not a tuple, but a string. So,I am going to make tuple and get the tuple value from the models and return it back to the template via `user_status_from_tuple`.

*models.py*

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ....

    def user_status_from_tuple(self):
        user_status = eval(self.user_status)
        return user_status[0]
```

In your template:

```
{{ user.user_status_from_tuple }}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be (provided, `user.user_status` should be an iterable)

```
{{ user.user_status.0 }}
```

Comment: This still results in ```(```